# Blank page on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, azure

I have an application running in Azure (trial account). So far so good, everything has been nice, except for a long deploy times (10-15 minutes).

I've done a deploy recently and got a lot of weird bugs I cannot trace. For example, if I log in and thus a cookie is created (I use FormsAuthentication) all I get from the application is a blank page, as in, absolutely nothing is sent to the browser. The application works fine in the ASP.NET Web Dev Server, IIS Express, even the Azure Emulator!

What could be the issue? Searching the web hasn't been much help, with only a couple of unrelated issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried logging into the site (if I correctly understood from one if the comments, the url is [versulo.com](http://www.versulo.com/)) and I didn't get any blank page with 404 status code.

However, there is another problem I spotted. Your site seems to be implementing caching inappropriately. The main page, the one from which you trigger the login and which is dynamic in nature contains an Expires header set at 5 minutes after the pages first load. That means that each call or redirect to that page within 5 minutes since it was first loaded, will be served from the browser's cache.

Because of that, after I login into your application I am redirected back to the home page which looks like I am not logged in. If I force a F5 refresh on the browser, then the page will indeed show me as logged in.

If instead of a refresh I try to login again (which is what I did in my first trials, since it looked like the login didn't work in the first time), I am getting an error page with the following message:

Sorry, there has been an error on the server.
500

The page looks like an application error page and even if it displays the 500 number, it is actually served with an HTTP 200.

So, while I am not 100% sure if this is also the cause of the problem described by you, you should remove the Expires headers from the dynamic pages your application is serving.

Comment: Weird is, when I created a new user at first I had the problem, now I don't. I doubt it's related to cache, because when I get a blank response the server logs show a 404 code, as does the response on the browser end, but thanks for pointing out the Expires headers.

Comment: @MirceaChirea, maybe during the OpenID login the redirect was being made to a nonexistent URL? I logged in using Yahoo. Which provider did you use? It is really hard to get the source of the of the problem without being able to reproduce it. However, at a first glance it does not seem to be related to Azure, but rather to the web app itself.

Comment: This happens regardless of logging in with OpenID or OAuth (FB). I am redirected to the page I was previously on and it displays fine. If I refresh I get 404 with nothing returner (should get a custom 404 page). This all works fine locally and on another host; I will wipe it over the weekend and try again from a clean state.

Comment: @MirceaChirea, I tried to refresh after the login, but everything worked just fine. No matter what I do I just don't the blank page with 404 HTTP status code. I am able to get the custom 404 page you are mentioning when asking for a nonexistent URL (like http://www.versulo.com/gigi). Maybe there is something on your side. Are you using a proxy or something that might block certain requests?

Comment: nope. Heck, I tried reinstalling the browser. This happens on my phone too. Oddly, it doesn't on the account I created yesterday (although it did initially), but still happens on older ones, even though there are no unexpected differences between them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10595/discussion-between-florin-dumitrescu-and-mircea-chirea)

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you're combining Forms Authentication with multiple instances. Are you using multiple instances? If that's the case, could you:

- Try to change it to 1 instance. Does this fix the issue?
- Try to make the following change to the web.config (configure machineKey): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Comment: Good point. However that has not been an issue in the past; will try both nonetheless.

Comment: No, that didn't fix anything, although I didn't expect it to do anything, as it's an issue with being logged in, logging works fine and the cookie is recognized by the other instance.

Comment: Actually, handling the MachineKey in Azure is done automatically since SDK 1.3 (http://bit.ly/hm9RhU). So, no need for manual steps. However a new Machine Key is propagated across all instances upon upgrade. To handle this situation one could use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg494983.aspx

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that one. +1

Answer (score 0):

> some partial views are not rendered at all;

Do you mean some pages are working fine, but others are not? It would be better if you can point out a pattern on what’s working and what’s not? For now, please make sure all referenced assemblies (except for default .NET assemblies and Windows Azure runtime) have Copy Local set to true. For example, MVC assemblies are considered as extensions to .NET, so please set Copy Local to true. In addition, you can also try to use Fiddler to monitor the requests to see what’s returned from the server.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: After checking again the partial view wasn't rendered because of a bug; the MVC and Azure assemblies are copy local, as well as other libraries I use.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a link to the application, or perhaps some source code?

When you say 'blank page', what is actually returned, a 404 / 500?

Have you inspected the IIS logs, or added some trace information to your code?

Have you tried accessing the service using it's ip address rather than domain name?

Comment: http://www.versulo.com - the status code is 404. This also happens if I use the Azure cloudapp.net subdomain.

Comment: The IIS logs don't show much; the page gets a 404 with an empty response; the favicon is received OK, so it has something to do with the MVC stack breaking: http://codepaste.net/9sra9g

Comment: Even weirder, it works by accessing the IP from the Azure OS; just not from the outside; this happens on my desktop, on my phone, with any browser, if I am logged in.

Comment: See screen shot here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/624582/stack_overflow_screen_shot.png

Comment: try logging out and then logging back in.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it to break.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10559/discussion-between-mircea-chirea-and-richard-astbury)